# Skip Certain Gutenberg Block in Loop

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have some WordPress Gutenberg blocks that I want to display in a different part of my theme. I know how to find the block and display it in my theme's template, but I don't know how to stop the block from showing with the rest of the blocks in the loop.

To clarify as an example: I have one block that I want to have in the admin area with the other blocks but I don't want to display it in the loop content. I need a way to skip it or filter it out in the normal loop. Then I use this code to output in another area of my theme:

```
function be_display_post_blockquote() {
 global $post;
 $blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content );
 foreach( $blocks as $block ) {
  if( 'lazyblock/area-2' === $block['blockName'] ) {
  echo render_block( $block );
  break;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with the above code is it duplicates the block to show with the other "normal" loop content and also in my new location. Can you help me write a function/filter to stop specific blocks from showing up in the loop?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out...

Here is the function to filter the content of the loop and remove a specific block from the output because you already outputted the content of that specific block in another location in your theme or theme template file.

```
//If single block exists on page or post don't show it with the other blocks
function remove_blocks() {
// Check if we're inside the main loop in a post or page
  if ( ( is_single() || is_page() ) && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {
    //parse the blocks so they can be run through the foreach loop
    $blocks = parse_blocks( get_the_content() );
    foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {
        //look to see if your block is in the post content -> if yes continue past it if no then render block as normal
        if ( 'lazyblock/top-of-page' === $block['blockName'] ) {
            continue;
        } else {
            echo render_block( $block );
        }
    }
  }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_blocks');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this makes all embed blocks (like YouTube block) stop working. I'm not sure how to get this working with YouTube and other Embed blocks.

Comment: Just to fill in here if anyone stumbles upon this like I did: To render embed etc. blocks you need to add the_content filter on the rendered block. Like this
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', render_block( $block ) );